# Handling Deduplication and Historic Data correction - Structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

Exploring to understand how to handle deduplication in spark structured streaming, when dealing with large volume of data and situations where watermark cannot be used.

**Situation**: data is published to a queue from data provider. Spark structured streaming reads the data from queue and writes to target storage. There could be possibility that occasionally incorrect data could be published by provider and consumer need to read the corrected data again from provider.

1. what is the best practice followed in spark structured streaming for data corrections? Do we maintain single queue/job/pipeline for both incremental and corrected history data? or we ask data provider to publish data to two different queues and maintain two different pipelines?
2. if we ask data provider to publish corrected data to same queue, then my understaning is that we cannot use withWatermark() to handle dedups. In such cases, how do we maintain state store, given it has to maintain complete and large data in memory? what is the best practice suggested?